# How to sort object array by time in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, time

I have a object array looking something like this:

- [0] = { transportnumber: '45', time: '10:28:00', date:"2017-01-16"}
- [1] = { transportnumber: '45', time: '10:38:00', date:"2017-01-16"}
- [2] = { transportnumber: '45', time: '10:48:00', date:"2017-01-16"}
- [3] = { transportnumber: '14', time: '10:12:00', date:"2017-01-16"}
- [4] = { transportnumber: '14', time: '10:24:00', date:"2017-01-16"}
- [5] = { transportnumber: '14', time: '10:52:00', date:"2017-01-16"}

The object array will always look like this unsorted. First by transport number and then by time. This due to the API I'm using.

My question is: How I can sort this array only by time?

I've tried using the sort function as seen below on my variable where the object array is stored but with no success:

```
allBuses.sort(function(a,b){
var c = a.time;
var d = b.time;

if(c > d){
return d
}

else return c
```

Comment: You're misusing `sort()`. Have you read [its documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)?

Comment: change your whole `if` statement with `return c > d ? 1 : -1`

Answer (score 30):

You could treat `time` as string and sort with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```js
var data = [{ transportnumber: '45', time: '10:28:00', date:"2017-01-16"}, { transportnumber: '45', time: '10:38:00', date:"2017-01-16" },{ transportnumber: '45', time: '10:48:00', date:"2017-01-16" }, { transportnumber: '14', time: '10:12:00', date:"2017-01-16" }, { transportnumber: '14', time: '10:24:00', date:"2017-01-16" }, { transportnumber: '14', time: '10:52:00', date:"2017-01-16"}];

data.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.time.localeCompare(b.time);
});

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Array.prototype. toSorted()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toSorted) and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to sort comparing time strings:

```js
const allBuses = [{ transportnumber: '45', time: '10:28:00', date:"2017-01-16"}, { transportnumber: '45', time: '10:38:00', date:"2017-01-16" },{ transportnumber: '45', time: '10:48:00', date:"2017-01-16" }, { transportnumber: '14', time: '10:12:00', date:"2017-01-16" }, { transportnumber: '14', time: '10:24:00', date:"2017-01-16" }, { transportnumber: '14', time: '10:52:00', date:"2017-01-16"}]

const sortedAllBuses = allBuses.toSorted(
  ({ time: a }, { time: b }) => a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0
)

console.log(sortedAllBuses)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if you want to add date also in consideration

```
data = []
data[0] = { transportnumber: '45', time: '10:28:00', date:"2017-01-16"}
data[1] = { transportnumber: '45', time: '10:38:00', date:"2017-01-16"}
data[2] = { transportnumber: '45', time: '10:48:00', date:"2017-01-16"}
data[3] = { transportnumber: '14', time: '10:12:00', date:"2017-01-16"}
data[4] = { transportnumber: '14', time: '10:24:00', date:"2017-01-16"}
data[5] = { transportnumber: '14', time: '10:52:00', date:"2017-01-16"}

data.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a.date < b.date)
        return -1

    if (a.date > b.date)
        return 1

    if (a.date == b.date) {
        if (a.time < b.time)
            return -1

        if (a.time > b.time)
            return 1

        return 0
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning **c** or **d**, which are the time values.  Your function needs to return...

- 0 if the values are the same
- Positive (>0) if **b** is lower than **a** (eg. 1)
- Negative (<0) if **a** if lower than **b** (eg. -1)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [ { transportnumber: '45', time: '10:28:00', date:"2017-01-16"}
,{ transportnumber: '45', time: '10:38:00', date:"2017-01-16"}
,{ transportnumber: '45', time: '10:48:00', date:"2017-01-16"}
,{ transportnumber: '14', time: '10:12:00', date:"2017-01-16"}
,{ transportnumber: '14', time: '10:24:00', date:"2017-01-16"}
,{ transportnumber: '14', time: '10:52:00', date:"2017-01-16"}];
array.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(b.date + " "+b.time) - new Date(a.date + " "+a.time);
});
console.log(array);
```

You could combine both date and time and sort like this

Answer (score 0):

```
    var data = [{ transportnumber: '45', time: '10:28:00', date:"2017-01-16"}, { transportnumber: '45', time: '10:38:00', date:"2017-01-16" },{ transportnumber: '45', time: '10:48:00', date:"2017-01-16" }, { transportnumber: '14', time: '10:12:00', date:"2017-01-16" }, { transportnumber: '14', time: '10:24:00', date:"2017-01-16" }, { transportnumber: '14', time: '10:52:00', date:"2017-01-16"}];

data.sort(function(a,b){

return b.time>a.time; 


})
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Check that the Array.prototype.sort() function can simply subtract b from a if you are comparing Numbers.. but in this case you are comparing Strings

Comment: This will not work correctly. The compare function should return a value that is either less than zero, zero, or more than zero. This will only return true or false, which is effectively 1 or 0 (so no negative numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    allBuses.sort(function(a,b){
    var c = new Date(a.date + ":"+ a.time).getTime();
    var d = new Date(b.date + ":"+b.time).getTime();
    console.log(c,d);
    return c -d;
    });
```

Comment: That will create a string like "2017-01-16:10:28:00" which is not consistent with the format supported in ECMA-262 and will very likely not be parsed correctly in most implementations (such as Safari and Firefox). It would be better to join with "T", but that too is somewhat problematic.

Answer (score 0):

If your application has [lodash](https://lodash.com/), you can do it very easily.

```
var sorted = _.orderBy(data,function(item){
return new Date(item.date + " " + data.time);
});
```